# SQL(Server) Filter Rows by Exact Conditions for Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have what appears to me to be a complicated SQL requirement where I need to query  a data table to return an exact match of recordsets that have different versions.

In words, I have multiple versions and each version can have one or more product | quotes combinations. If I pass a product | quote combination, I want to return all versions with **only those exact combinations** (nothing more and nothing less).

On top of that, I have scenarios where some product | quotes are repeated multiple times (as a package) so I need to group those as a distinct entity and consider them only as one for each version.

It's getting **very** complex and I am not sure if SQL is even the best tool to handle this or if I just lack the advanced (?) skill set to accomplish the task.

That said, here's a sample dataset (organized visualization shown here, see below for actual data set that can be copied):

[image]

Expected v Actual Results are here:

[image]

SQL is below (I also have dug into `EXCEPT` a bit and think that may help, but I am losing my ability look at this anymore!):

**NOTE** - HAVING Count(version_num) needs to be changed to 1, 2, 3 etc. based on number of product | quote combos entered.

```
SELECT Account_No, version_num, -- LineOfBus, ProductNo, QuoteNo, 
            SUM(CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(TotalPremium) = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2),TotalPremium) 
                END) As TotalPremium 
        FROM 
        (SELECT t.Account_No, t.version_num, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ISNull(t.PackageIndicator,'0') = '1' THEN 'Package' Else t.Lob 
            END AS LineOfBus,
            t.ProductNo, t.QuoteNo, 
            ISNull(CASE 
                        WHEN ISNUMERIC(t.TotalPremium) = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2),t.TotalPremium) 
                    END, 0) TotalPremium 
            FROM zzzScottTest as T
            WHERE t.version_num IN
                (SELECT sqVersionNumber.version_num
                    FROM
                    /* this captures unique package product records (or just stand alone records as well) */
                    (SELECT DISTINCT sqUnique.version_num, Count(sqUnique.version_num) VersionCount 
                        FROM
                        /* grab list of all uniquer version, product, quote combinations (use distinct to combine package */
                            (SELECT DISTINCT version_num, productNo, quoteNo
                                FROM zzzScottTest
                                WHERE Account_No = 'b' /* pass as parameter */
                                    AND ProductNo IN ('8888') /* pass as parameter */
                                    AND QuoteNo IN ('999') /* pass as parameter */
                            ) AS sqUnique
                        GROUP BY version_num
                        HAVING Count(version_num) = 1 /* pass as variable based on number of products, quotes */
                    ) as sqVersionNumber
                )
            AND t.Account_no = 'b' /* pass as parameter */
            AND t.ProductNo IN ('8888') /* pass as parameter */
            AND t.QuoteNo IN ('999') /* pass as parameter */) as sqLOB
        GROUP BY Account_No, version_num --, LineOfBus, ProductNo, QuoteNo
```

Lastly - sample dataset to copy:

```
Account_No  Version_Num LOB ProductNo   QuoteNo TotalPremium    PackageIndicator    RowNo
b   1   GL  1234    987 100 1   1 
b   1   Auto    1234    987 200 1   2
b   1   WC  7891    321 300 0   3
b   2   GL  2222    222 100 0   1
b   2   Auto    4567    654 200 0   2
b   3   GL  2222    222 100 0   1
b   4   GL  2222    222 110 0   1
b   5   GL  2222    222 115 0   1
b   5   Auto    4567    654 250 0   2
b   6   GL  1234    987 100 1   1
b   6   Auto    1234    987 200 1   2
b   6   WC  7891    321 350 0   3
b   7   WC  7891    321 350 0   1
b   7   Prop    8888    999 400 0   2
b   8   GL  1234    987 111 1   1
b   8   Auto    1234    987 222 1   2
b   9   GL  2222    222 100 0   1
b   9   Auto    4567    654 200 0   2
b   9   WC  9999    888 150 0   3
b   10  GL  2222    222 100 0   1
```

Comment: Your requirements are not complicated; I think you are overthinking the query. I'm trying to read your SQL but it's hard with overly nested sub-selects. Plus it doesn't help not knowing whether you have all the parameters in there for testing purposes only or if you are actually using them in the final form.

Comment: @Anand - I agree I am overthinking. I feel like I'm in over my SQL head here. Please suggest better formatting for sub queries. Or feel free to edit question directly. Parameters will be used in final form based on data set. `ProductNo`, `QuoteNo` and `HAVING Count(version_num)` can be adjusted based on sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague, much more versed in SQL then I solved this issue.

```
SELECT U.[account_no],U.[version_num],
      SUM(CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(U.TotalPremium) = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2),TotalPremium) 
            END) As TotalPremium 
  FROM [dbo].[zzzScottTest] as U 

  INNER JOIN

    (Select distinct U1.Account_No, U1.version_num From dbo.[zzzScottTest] U1
        Inner Join 
            (SELECT DISTINCT ST2.Account_No, ST2.version_num,
                substring((SELECT ','+  ST1.ProductNo  AS [text()]
                        FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT Account_No, version_num, ProductNo, QuoteNo 
                                FROM [zzzScottTest]) ST1
                        WHERE ST1.version_num = ST2.version_num  
                            AND ST1.Account_No = ST2.Account_No  
                        ORDER BY ST1.Account_No,ST1.version_num
                        FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 2, 1000) [AllProduct]
                ,
                substring((SELECT ','+  ST3.QuoteNo  AS [text()]
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Account_No, version_num, ProductNo, QuoteNo 
                        FROM [zzzScottTest] ) ST3
                        WHERE ST3.version_num = ST2.version_num  
                            AND ST3.Account_No = ST2.Account_No  
                        ORDER BY ST3.version_num
                        FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 2, 1000) [AllQuote]
        FROM dbo.[zzzScottTest] ST2 
        GROUP BY ST2.Account_No, ST2.version_num, ST2.ProductNo, ST2.QuoteNo) Temp 
        ON
            Temp.Account_No = U1.Account_No and 
            Temp.version_num = U1.version_num and 
            Temp.[AllProduct] = '8888' and
            Temp.[AllQuote]  = '999'
            ) AS Final 
        ON
            Final.Account_No = U.Account_No  and
            Final.version_num = U.version_num 
        GROUP BY U.account_no, U.[version_num]
```